# Parsing csv using conditional statement in awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv file

file.csv

```
C75ADANXX,5,20,,AGGCAGAA,AGAGTAGA,,,,,AB
C75ADANXX,5,21,,AGGCAGAA,GTAAGGAG,,,,,AB
C75ADANXX,5,22,,AGGCAGAA,ACTGCATA,,,,,AB
C75ADANXX,5,23,,AGGCAGAA,AAGGAGTA,,,,,TC
C75ADANXX,5,24,,AGGCAGAA,CTAAGCCT,,,,,TC
C75ADANXX,5,25,,TCCTGAGC,GCGTAAGA,,,,,TC
```

when I run the following awk command :

```
awk -F "," '{print$11}' file.csv  ##prints last cloumn
```

i want to extract lines with TC ; but the following command prints nothing

```
awk -F "," '{if($11==TC){print$0}}' file.csv
```

Where am I going wrong in writing the command ? Thank you.

Comment: can't reproduce, please specify your platform.

Comment: try `awk -F, '$11~/TC/'`

Answer (score 1):

modified the command to

```
awk -F "," '{if($11=="TC\r"){print$0}}' file.csv
```

this file was copied from windows , it had a carriage return character at the end of the line which was obviously not seen when you print only last column.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify**

> ```
> awk -F "," '{if($11==TC){print$0}}' file.csv
> ```

**To**

```
awk -F "," '{if($11=="TC"){print$0}}' file.csv
```

**OR even simple**

```
awk -F, '$11=="TC"' file.csv
```

- > **`if($11==TC)`**  Since variable `TC` is not defined before (because no quotes used, `awk` treats `TC` as variable **not** as string), it evaluates `false` always, so it prints nothing.

Comment: Still doesn't work Akshay, I tried both the solutions provided by you. Does it work at your end ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

grep ",TC$"  file.csv